# I need to create a table with accumulated values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this input table:

T1

```
f1 f2
1  S1
1  S2
1  S3
2  S4
3  S5
3  S6
```

And need to produce this output table:

T2

```
g1 g2
1  S1+S2+S3
2  S4
3  S5+S6
```

S# values are strings. g1 is the grouped by value of f1. g2 is the concatenation of values f2.

Can I write a Postgres SQL statement to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
select f1, string_agg(f2, '+') f2s
from t1
group by f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `string_agg()`?

```
select f1, string_agg(f2, '+')
from t1
group by f1;
```

I don't really recommend `string_agg()` unless you have a specific need for it.  Arrays are more useful than strings:

```
select f1, array_agg(f2)
from t1
group by f1;
```

Also note that the ordering is not guaranteed for the elements in the string or array.  You can add `order by f2` if that is the ordering you want.